# How to move to next slide in PowerPoint Web App?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, sharepoint, web-application

I have a PowerPoint file in SharePoint. When I copy a link to share the file (e.g. in a meeting agenda), then I click on that link, it opens up in the [PowerPoint Web App](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/use-powerpoint-web-app-in-a-sharepoint-library-0d63f6bb-4a11-43af-8c3b-46a2f2a1804c). In there, if I'm editing a slide, it doesn't let me move to the next slide with PgDn/right arrow/down arrow, unless I am in the left navigation pane or in Slide Show Mode. But they don't work if I am on the slide itself.
Is there a different **keystroke that will let me move through the slides**?

Comment: What about arrow down? You need to select the slide on the left pane.

Comment: All the typical "next slide" commands like arrow down, PgDn, etc don't work when I am in the slide itself. You are right they do work if I'm in the left pane.  I'll edit my question.